# Push notification on ios9 app

Tags: node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9, node-apn

My app communicates with a backend nodejs server (node, express and mongoose).
I store users and messages in MongoDB.

When a user sends a new message to another one:

- I update the messages DB
- I send to the destination user a push notification

I have few questions regarding push notifications handling and performance:

- Is it a better way to have an APN server separate from my backend server (with node-pushserver for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushserver) and request for a push notification with a REST api call from my iOS app

or

- Is it a better way to directly implement the push notification in my nodejs server when the messages MongoDB is updated (with node-apn for example: https://github.com/argon/node-apn)

I precise thay my backend server will be host by AWS soon.

If there is another solution better than above, feel free to correct me :)

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: I am also implement push notification many time and according to my experience node-apn is best way to implement the push notification rather then then node-pushserver. you can implement apn push notification on both production and development environment and there also lot of options you can change in apn.

Comment: But is it not a little bit dirty to implement apn push notification in the same code I do the MongoDB update?

Comment: Mongodb update operations are fast.I think you do't need to worry about the mongodb updates.I make the chatting app and in every message i send the notification and store them in to database and thousand of message and notification at per second and thousand update operation are perform in mongodb

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal: so in the same route I can fetch the DB, update it, and then use apn to push a notification? No worries about performance or readability of the code?